# web2py: encrypt uploaded files

Tags: web2py

I am in the process of writing a healthcare application in web2py and it needs to be HIPAA compliant. One of the many requirements is encryption of patient identifying data. I need to encrypt uploaded files preferably with AES. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of python encryption libraries you can use:

pycrypto  https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/doc/
  pyopenssl http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/  (wraps openssl)
  pyNSS     (wraps NSS)

If you are really concerned with cryptographic integrity, I would stick with a FIPS or NSA Suite B compliant cryptographic library.  There are also proprietary cryptographic libraries that are C/C++ based.  You can always use python ctypes or SWIG to wrapper them.

Comment: I wasn't looking for an encryption library, but an automatic method of doing the encryption for the files within web2py.